# Probability distribution derived from gamma function - does it have a name?

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, probability-distributions, terminology, gamma-function

Consider the complex gamma function, denoted by $\Gamma(\sigma+it)$.

Now, let's fix $\sigma$ and let t vary. Then consider the following expression:

$$|\Gamma(\sigma+it)|^2$$

For any choice of $\sigma$ such that $\Gamma(\sigma)$ isn't a pole, this will appear to be (almost) a two-sided probability density function, save for that it isn't normalized. It decays around as quickly as $e^{-|t|}$, somewhat resembles the function $e^{-\sqrt{1+t^2}}$, and appears related to the hyperbolic distribution.

1. Is there a precise closed-form expression for this function in terms of elementary or Louvillian functions?
2. Is there a name for this probability distribution (assuming it's normalized)?

This question was originally asked on MSE [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1454626/probability-distribution-derived-from-gamma-function-does-it-have-a-name). It got some attention but no answers; someone commented I should repost here.

Comment: This happens to be the weight for a subfamily of Meixner-Pollaczek orthogonal polynomials (http://homepage.tudelft.nl/11r49/askey/ch1/par7/par7.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is called Generalized Hyperbolic Secant Distributions. See  Generalized Hyperbolic Secant Distributions of W. L. Harkness and M. L. Harkness (http://www.jstor.org/stable/2283852). 
In particular, see equation (3) in that paper and use the fact that $\overline{\Gamma(z)}=\Gamma(\bar z)$